# Extract data faster from Redis and store in Panda Dataframe by avoiding key generation

Tags: python, pandas, redis

I am using Redis with Python to store my per second ticker data (price and volume of an instrument). I am performing `r.hget(instrument,key)` and facing the following issue.

My `key` (string) looks like `01/01/2020-09:32:01` and goes on incrementing per second till the user specified interval. 
For example `01/01/2020-09:32:01`
`01/01/2020-09:32:02` `01/01/2020-09:32:03 ...`.

My `r.hget(instrument,key)` result looks like`b'672.2,432'`(price and volume separated by a comma).

The issue am facing is that a user can specify a long time interval, like 2 years, that is, he/she wants the data from `01/01/2020` to `31/12/2020` (d/m/y format).So to perform the get operation I have to first generate timestamps for that period and then perform the get operation to form a panda dataframe. The generation of this datastamp to use as key for get operation is slowing down my process terribly (but it also ensures that the data is in strict ordering. For example `01/01/2020-09:32:01` will definitely be before `01/01/2020-09:32:02`). Is there another way to achieve the same?

If I simply do `r.hgetall(...)` I wont be able to satisfy the time interval condition of user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

redis sorted set's are good fit for such range queries, sorted sets are made up of unique member's with a score, in your case timestamp can be score in epoch seconds and price and volume can be member, however member in sorted set is unique you may consider adding timestamp to make it unique.

```
zadd instrument 1577883600 672.2,432,1577883600
zadd instrument 1577883610 672.2,412,1577883610
```

After adding members to the set you can do range queries using **zrangebyscore** as below

```
zrangebyscore instrument 1577883600 1577883610
```

If your instrument contains many values then consider sharding it into multiple for example per month each set like instrument:202001, instrument:202002 and so on.

following are good read on this topic

[Sorted Set Time Series](https://redislabs.com/redis-best-practices/time-series/sorted-set-time-series/)

[Sharding Structure](https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/01chapter-9-reducing-memory-use/9-2-sharded-structures/)

Comment: Thanks, Sorted sets are better suited for my implementation than the hashes. Timestamp serves as score and running time has improved significantly.

Comment: Welcome, glad to know it help.

Answer (score 0):

*So to perform the get operation I have to first generate timestamps for that period and then perform the get operation...*

No. This is the problem.
Make a function that calculates the timestamps and yield a smaller set of values, for a smaller time span (one week or one month).

So the new workflow will be in batches, see this loop:

- generate a small set of timestamps
- fetch items from redis

Pros:

- minimize the memory usage
- easy to change your current code to this new algo.

I don't know about redis specific functions, so other specific solutions can be better. My idea is a general approach, I used it with success for other problems.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [RedisTimeSeries](https://oss.redislabs.com/redistimeseries/) for this task? It is a redis module that is tailored exactly for the sort of task you are describing.

You can keep two timeseries per instrument that will hold price and value.
With RedisTimeSeries is it easy the query over different ranges and you can use the filtering mechanism to group different series, instrument families for example, and query all of them at once.

```
// create your timeseries
TS.CREATE instrument:price LABELS instrument violin type string
TS.CREATE instrument:volume LABELS instrument violin type string

// add values
TS.ADD instrument:price 123456 9.99
TS.ADD instrument:volume 123456 42

// query timeseries
TS.RANGE instrument:price - + 
TS.RANGE instrument:volume - + 

// query multiple timeseries by filtering according to labels
TS.MRANGE - + FILTER instrument=violin
TS.MRANGE - + FILTER type=string
```

RedisTimeSeries allows running queries with aggregations such as average standard-deviation, and uses double-delta compression which can reduce your memory usage by over 90%.

You can checkout a benchmark [here](https://redislabs.com/blog/redistimeseries-version-1-2-benchmarks/).